# Decrypt encrypted column in SQL Server which is non-human readable format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I have imported some production data into a table. In that table, some columns are encrypted as non-human readable format. For ex: `'Õ;Q€Kùu'`.

I have tried to convert it to human readable format liket his:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 'Õ;Q€Kùu')
```

But it didn't return the correct output. Is it possible to convert the non-human readable data into human readable format?

Comment: Are you sure it's encrypted? Not just the character encoding broken down somewhere along the way? If it is encrypted, you will need the key.

Comment: no..its an encrypted data for sure

Comment: Then you have to get back to whoever gave you that data and ask them how to decrypt it.

Comment: if it is encrypted, then you need to decrypt it the same way before able to "read" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot decrypt that column. You should know encryption key. It should be in software code.  However there are some MD5 decrypt sites they have encryption key database it may help.
Try search google with `encrypt MD5`